# Castle Windsor WCF Client service registration based on convention

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, fluent

I have a client-server application, which intercommunicate via WCF. They also both use Castle Windsor for resolving dependencies.

My goal, is to completely avoid having to explicitly register server, or client WCF endpoints.
I have achieved the server-side by 'convention' using the following code

```
// registers all services which implement exactly 1 [ServiceContract]
_windsorContainer.Register(
AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().IncludeNonPublicTypes().Where(
    t => 1 == (from i in t.GetInterfaces() where i.IsDefined(typeof(ServiceContractAttribute), true) select i).Count())
    .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.PerWcfSession()
    .ActAs(new DefaultServiceModel().AddEndpoints(
         WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new NetTcpBinding())
             .At("net.tcp://" + LocalAddress.ToString() + ":7601/" + c.ServiceType.Name),
         WcfEndpoint.FromEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint())
            ))

    ).WithService.Select(
    (Type type, Type[] baseTypes) => from i in type.GetInterfaces() where i.IsDefined(typeof(ServiceContractAttribute), true) select i
    )
);
```

This code will find all classes in the current assembly, and any which implement a service-contract interface (identified by the ServiceContract attribute) will be registered (with UDP discovery) at the address "net.tcp://localhost:7601/[service-contract-interface-name]".

Now, I just want the client-side of the equation.

Typically, to use castle to generate client-proxies for WCF contracts, the following code will work:

```
var model = new DefaultClientModel
{
    Endpoint = WcfEndpoint.ForContract<IServiceContract>().BoundTo(new NetTcpBinding()).Discover(typeof(IServiceContract))
};

container.Register(
    Component.For<ChannelReconnectPolicy>(),
    Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfClient.ForChannels(model),
);
```

What I want, is for Castle to do this kind of registration for all 'service-contract' interfaces in a given assembly - however the AllTypes helper seems to return only classes, not interfaces (which I guess makes it an 'AllClasses', not 'AllTypes'!)... Can Castle do this, and what is the syntax? Krzysztof? (help!)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Im wondering exactly same thing... Good question! +1

Comment: Ah, yes I think I did - I will have to take a look back at the code - I will get back to you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for such a late reply - a developer's life is never a quiet one!

I dug out the code, and its not as 'succinct' as I would have liked, perhaps someone can look at integrating something like this in to Castle... but here goes...

```
// these are all the namespaces that will be scanned for WCF service contracts
string[] remoteServiceNamespaces 
    = new string[] { "MyContracts.Services", "Interlinq" };

// everything from here on is in the Castle DLLs (all the types)
List<IRegistration> clientContractRegistrations = new List<IRegistration>();
foreach (
    var interfaceContract in
    (from s in remoteServiceNamespaces
    select (from i in Assembly.LoadWithPartialName(s).GetTypes()
        where i.IsInterface
        && 
        i.IsDefined(typeof(ServiceContractAttribute), false)
        select i)).SelectMany( x => x )
    )
{
    ServiceContractAttribute attr 
        = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
                    interfaceContract, 
                    typeof(ServiceContractAttribute)) 
                    as ServiceContractAttribute;
    if (null != attr)
    {
    WcfClientModelBase model = null;

    // here we handle the case of the service being duplex...
    if (null != attr.CallbackContract)
    {
        model = new DuplexClientModel
        {
        // All the automatically registered services will use NetTcp, 
        // and will discover their addresses (you could use binding 
        // inference aswell if you liked)
        // here I have a method called 'CreateNetTcpBinding' which 
        // creates my custom binding that ALL my services use.
        Endpoint = 
                 WcfEndpoint.ForContract(interfaceContract)
                 .BoundTo(CreateNetTcpBinding())
                 .Discover(interfaceContract)
                 .PreferEndpoint(list => list[0])
        }.Callback(_windsor.Resolve(attr.CallbackContract));
    }
    else
    {
        model = new DefaultClientModel
        {
        Endpoint = WcfEndpoint.ForContract(interfaceContract)
                    .BoundTo(new NetTcpBinding())
                    .Discover(interfaceContract)
                    .PreferEndpoint(list => list[0])
        };
    }
    clientContractRegistrations.Add(WcfClient.ForChannels(model));
    }
}

// now that we've built our registration list, let's actually register 
// them all with Windsor
_windsor.Register(
    clientContractRegistrations.ToArray()
    );
```